# Laravel validation: One input box, either digit or email; OR logic

Tags: laravel, validation

I understand that for complex validation, I can make a validation function but I am looking for a shorter path if exists. Here is the scenario:

```
<input type="text" name="query" placeholder="Enter Email or Mobile number">
```

For validation however I can check if it is either email or digit. There is no OR logic, or I cannot find any.

```
$request->validate([
    'query' => 'email' //cannot have 'email OR digit:8,13'
]);
```

Comment: You can either create a validation from a [Closure](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/validation#using-closures) (check if it is a valid email or digits else return false), or create your own [validation rule](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/validation#custom-validation-rules). It is not that hard to check the documentation that explains this...

Comment: I was aware of the custom validation rules. But not the Closure. I will check and see how that works. Thanks a lot for the tip.

Answer (score -1):

@Aaron you may use the `sometimes` closure:

```
$input = $this->query;

$validator = Validator::make($input, [
    'query' => ['required'],
]);

// Apply the email rule when 'query' is not numeric
$validator->sometimes('query', 'email', function($input, $item) {
    return ! is_numeric($item);
});

// Apply the digits_between rule when 'query' is numeric
$validator->sometimes('query', 'digits_between:8,13', function($input, $item) {
    return is_numeric($item);
});
```